# Bootstrap Wizard/ Step Form

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a bootstrap step form, but it doesn't want to work. I'm using this code: 
https://codepen.io/digitalavinash/pen/VjyAXx?fbclid=IwAR2j8hRIG0gnKGYEDwhr15VxAAaf7nNtkbLvEIQMBg_lfdjDpjeWbEYxAP0

but I get this result:

https://i.gyazo.com/81364249357de09595c722f7b50ba65c.png

I don't really know, what I'm doing wrong, I just copy-paste it.

I have bootstrap links included, like

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and at the bottom of my body class, I also have these links:

```
<!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!-- Popper.JS -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!-- jQuery Custom Scroller CDN -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
```

Don't know if I'm trying to use a wrong version of scripts. Could you help me out please?

My full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>title.com</title>


    <link rel="icon" href="titleicon.png" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- Scrollbar Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">






</head>

<body>

<!-- SUBSCRIBE Youtube Channel
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQM5ye1xR4vJgtga0ryud2Q/
-->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <section>
        <div class="wizard">
            <div class="wizard-inner">
                <div class="connecting-line"></div>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

                    <li role="presentation" class="active">
                        <a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" title="Step 1">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                        <a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" title="Step 2">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                        <a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step3" role="tab" title="Step 3">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                        <a href="#complete" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="complete" role="tab" title="Complete">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <form role="form">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="step1">
                        <h3>Step 1</h3>
                        <p>This is step 1</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step2">
                        <h3>Step 2</h3>
                        <p>This is step 2</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Previous</button></li>
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step3">
                        <h3>Step 3</h3>
                        <p>This is step 3</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Previous</button></li>
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default next-step">Skip</button></li>
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-info-full next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="complete">
                        <h3>Complete</h3>
                        <p>You have successfully completed all steps.</p>
                      <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQM5ye1xR4vJgtga0ryud2Q/" target="_blank">SUBSCRIBE Youtube Channel</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
   </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    //Initialize tooltips
    $('.nav-tabs > li a[title]').tooltip();

    //Wizard
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {

        var $target = $(e.target);

        if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    $(".next-step").click(function (e) {

        var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
        $active.next().removeClass('disabled');
        nextTab($active);

    });
    $(".prev-step").click(function (e) {

        var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
        prevTab($active);

    });
});

function nextTab(elem) {
    $(elem).next().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
}
function prevTab(elem) {
    $(elem).prev().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS:

```
.wizard {
    margin: 20px auto;

}

    .wizard .nav-tabs {
        position: relative;
        margin: 40px auto;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border-bottom-color: #ff00ff;
    }

    .wizard > div.wizard-inner {
        position: relative;
    }

.connecting-line {
    height: 2px;
    background: #ff00ff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
    color: #555555;
    cursor: default;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

span.round-tab {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ff00ff;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
span.round-tab i{
    color:##00ffff;
}
.wizard li.active span.round-tab {
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ff00ff;

}
.wizard li.active span.round-tab i{
    color: #5bc0de;
}

span.round-tab:hover {
    color: #333;
    border: 2px solid #ff00ff;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li {
    width: 25%;
}

.wizard li:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 46%;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #5bc0de;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.wizard li.active:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 46%;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #ff00ff;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li a {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

    .wizard .nav-tabs > li a:hover {
        background: transparent;
    }

.wizard .tab-pane {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.wizard h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
}

@media( max-width : 585px ) {

    .wizard {
        width: 90%;
        height: auto !important;
    }

    span.round-tab {
        font-size: 16px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
    }

    .wizard .nav-tabs > li a {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
    }

    .wizard li.active:after {
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        left: 35%;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share the code that you have so I can replicate it and see what the problem is

Comment: Just edited the original post with the full code. It's the same as here [link](https://codepen.io/digitalavinash/pen/VjyAXx?fbclid=IwAR2j8hRIG0gnKGYEDwhr15VxAAaf7nNtkbLvEIQMBg_lfdjDpjeWbEYxAP0)

Comment: if you inspect codepen carefully, you will see that its bootstrap version is 3.x, https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js. If you really need to stick to version 4, then I suggest google for version 4 wizard.

Comment: Could you tell me please, which links ands scripts do i exactly need? I've got a tons of links in my code, and can't really find the solution there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can include https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css
above link for bootstrap css 4.1.3 and include you jquery.min.js in header. It may help.

Comment: Got the same results :/

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have added validate.js in your footer scripts. It will work